# postgres does not save all data after committing

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

In my golang project that use gorm as ORM and posgress as database, in some sitution when I begin transaction to
change three tables and commiting, just one of tables changes. two other tables data does not change.
any idea how it might happen?

you can see example below

```
o := *gorm.DB
tx := o.Begin()
invoice.Number = 1
err := tx.Save(&invoice)
if err != nil {
    err2 := tx.RollBack().Error()
    return err
}


receipt.Ref = "1331"
err = tx.Save(&receipt)
if err != nil {
    err2 := tx.RollBack().Error()
    return err
}

payment.status = "succeed"
err = tx.Save(&payment)
if err != nil {
    err2 := tx.RollBack().Error()
    return err
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    err2 := tx.Rollback()
    return err
}
```

Just payment data changed and I'm not getting any error.

Comment: In the second line isn't tx supposed to created from DB? Like ```tx := o.Begin()```

Comment: yes, I should edit that here... thanks.

Comment: Does this code even compile? You have a mix of Rollback and RollBack, you are calling the `tx.Error` member as a function. After each save you assign `tx.Save(*)` to `err` and then return that from the function, even though `tx.Save` returns a `*gorm.DB` which is incompatible with the error interface.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are mistakenly using save points! In PostgreSQL, we can have nested transactions, that is, defining save points make the transaction split into parts. I am not a Golang programmer and my primary language is not Go, but as I guess the problem is "tx.save" which makes a SavePoint, and does not save the data into database. SavePoints makes a new transaction save point, and thus, the last table commits.

Comment: this bug does not happen all the  time and save point does not support in my gorm version(v1).
Save() method just work like below in gorm:

```db.First(&user)

user.Name = "jinzhu 2"
user.Age = 100
db.Save(&user)


//// UPDATE users SET name='jinzhu 2', age=100, birthday='2016-01-01', updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id=111
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the Node.js, then any async function callback returns an error as the first argument. In Go, we follow the same norm.

https://medium.com/rungo/error-handling-in-go-f0125de052f0